# Installing mod_wsgi in Apache2.4 on Windows 7 x64

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

My current setup `Python3.5 x64`, `Apache2.4`

I am learning `Python` and `django`. I want to run django app using `Apache`.

I download `mod_wsgi` binary from here http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

I picked up this one: `mod_wsgi-4.4.23+ap24vc14-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl`

I got `mod_wsgi.so` after extract. I added that file in `apache modules directory`.

After that I added following code in httpd.conf file

```
    LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

    WSGIScriptAlias / C:/djangoprojects/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py
    WSGIPythonPath /C:/djangoprojects/mysite

    <Directory C:/djangoprojects/mysite/mysite>
    <Files wsgi.py>
    Require all granted
    </Files>
    </Directory>
```

But I am getting following error.

```
     httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 183 of C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: The specified module could not be found.
```

I am not able to load `mod_wsgi` module. Need help.

Comment: Which is line 183 ? and the error is self-explained. the file cannot be found.

Comment: Is the file really exist ? Check it.

Comment: yes. it is present there.

Comment: I can't understand why it is not able to load though all my applications are x64

Answer (score 1):

I checked my installation and found that `python for all` was missing.

I reinstall `python3.5` with `custom configurations`  and enable `python for all` option.